# How to read 前 on its own?

Tags: usage, kanji, readings

For example, when you're on a homepage, and on the bottom, you can go to the previous page with the 前 button and the next page with the 次 button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [前]{まえ} and [次]{つぎ} as in [前]{まえ}のページ and [次]{つぎ}のページ.

Comment: And what about 前ページ ?

Comment: @oldergod Well, 前ページ can be ぜんページ, but then it is easily confused with 全ページ, so I'd recommend [前]{まえ}のページ.